# How do I scale text in jspdf?

Tags: jspdf

I have been using http://raw.githack.com/MrRio/jsPDF/master/docs/jsPDF.html#text and trying in jspdf to use the following code to vertically scale text by 80%:

```
doc.text('LIFE', 1, 60, {charSpace: '10'}, transform="matrix(1,0,0,0.8,0,0)");
```

The **matrix[3]** corresponds with "sy": http://raw.githack.com/MrRio/jsPDF/master/docs/Matrix.html

It does not seem to have any effect at all. The outcome I am wanting is for the effect similar to the CSS transform:scaleY(0.8) style.

How can I scale my text so that it is "shorter" than the default?